# Outdated tokens in use

Tags: tokens

we have the following in the CiviCRM System Status, we tried to solve it with no luck, is it related to some template some where? Can you please help?

1. Please review your contribution_invoice_receipt message template and remove references to the token {$display_name} as it has been replaced by {contact.display_name}
2. Please review your membership_offline_receipt message template and remove references to the token {receipt_text_renewal} as it has been replaced by {receipt_text}
3. Please review your pledge_reminder message template and remove references to the token {$domain} as it has been replaced by {no longer available / relevant}
4. Please review your pledge_reminder message template and remove references to the token {$contact} as it has been replaced by {no longer available / relevant}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the solution from when you asked this question a [few days ago](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45422/civicrm-system-status-warning)?

Comment: Thanks Lars SG. Yes, We have tried to locate the template and for example we have also tried to locate $display_name and receipt_text_renewal. Is it under Administer -> Communication -> Mange Templates? We have searched all the templates for these 2 tokens with no luck. Is it under PHP codes? Thanks

Comment: Administer > Communications > Message Templates > System Workflow Messages tab.